Optimising redission client
Context on the current config.
I am using redission with following config
command timeout - 100ms
connection timeout - 150ms.
retry count - 1.
cluster mode - enabled
retry interval - 100ms
Recently we faced an issue where our 50 hosts, connected to redis node, refreshed a lot of their connections and a lot of timeout exception was observed. A lot of API calls failed due to 100ms timeout that we had set. CPU utilisation spiked during this connection storm.
Got to know that when command timeout happens redission clients drops the particular connection and recreates it.
How can we optimise this?
What if we set connection timeout to 2 seconds. Can there be a case where an API call takes 2000 + 100 * 3 ms inspite of setting command timeout as 100, 3 comes from retry count.
Does redission client try to make connection while making API call or is the connection pooling thing happens in an async way.
